# Javascript pdf fill dropdown list with Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, pdf, scripting, dropdown

I would like to fill my Dropdownlist named "mondayHours" with a for loop with numbers from 1-12 can anyone help me? I read some articles in the web but I couldn't find the right solution.

I have begun with this...

```
for(i=0; i <= 10; i++){
    this.getField("mondayHours").setItems([i.toString()]);
}
```

But nothing happens.

When I use this, its create dropdown items with 0.25 - ...

```
this.getField("mondayHours").setItems(["0.25","0.5","1","1.25"....]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like what I have below...

```
var hours = [] // an empty array
for(i=1; i <= 12; i++){
    hours.push(i); // add each number to the end of the array
}

this.getField("mondayHours").setItems(hours); // set the items list to the array
```